# How to display users that are subscribed to a plan with stripe

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to create an admin dashboard for my application.

The goal is display all users that have an active subscription through stripe. Currently when the page loads it is displaying all users regardless if they have an active subscription or not.

In my blade file:

```html
<tbody>
    @for ($x = 0; $x < count($users); $x++)
        <tr class='clickable-row'
            data-href="{{ url('/applicationDetails', $users[$x]['id']) }}">
            <td scope="row">
                {{$users[$x]['id']}}
            </td>
            <td scope="row">
                {{$users[$x]['email']}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endfor
</tbody>
```

In my web route:

```php
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    $users = App\User::where('processed', 0)->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->subscribed('SAM Registration')) {
            return view('admin/dashboard', ['user' => $user, 'users' => $users]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried stripe customer object?

Comment: You can't return a `view()` in a loop... I mean you can, but it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @TimLewis what if there's only one result passing the if statement inside the loop?

Comment: The reason is that you pass on all the `users => $users` which contain all the users that have `'processed', 0`. This means it will contain users that are not subsribed to `'plan_name'`.The query is what you should change. Not sure how one would do that with `Stripe`

Comment: Show the subscribed method in your User model and that would be helpful

Comment: @CaddyDZ Then it would work, and it *technically* works in a loop, but logically, there are better ways to determine `$user`, such as querying from the database, looping and assigning/breaking, etc. It's just a weird approach, and I'm not sure why they're doing it. Maybe using `filter()`, something like `$users = $users->filter(function($user){ return $user->subscribed("..."); });` if querying is not possible. That would leverage the need for a `foreach()` loop, and allow returning of only subscribed users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would wanna do the *is subscribed* check in a query instead of in-memory. This means you need to use something along the lines:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    $users = App\User::query()
        ->where('processed', 0)
        ->whereHas('subscriptions', function ($query) {
            $query->active()
                ->where('stripe_plan', 'plan_name');
        })
        ->get();

    return view('admin/dashboard', ['users' => $users]);    
});
```

With the `$users` passed to the view, you can then simply iterate them with a nice foreach loop:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="{{ url('/applicationDetails', $user->id) }}">
            <td scope="row">{{ $user->id }}</td>
            <td scope="row">{{ $user->email }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endfor
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

View

```
<tbody>

    @foreach($users as $user)

        <tr class='clickable-row' data-href="{{ url('/applicationDetails', $user['id']) }}">

            <td scope="row">
                {{$user['id']}}

            </td>

            <td scope="row">
                {{$user['email']}}

            </td>

        </tr>

    @endforeach

</tbody>
```

Route

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {

    $users = App\User::where('processed', 0)->get();
    $users2 = [];

    foreach ($users as $user) {

        if ($user->subscribed('plan_name')) {

            $users2[] = $user;

        }
    }

    return view('admin/dashboard', ['users' => $users2]);

});
```

Comment: You could eliminate the loop and extra array by writing `$users = array_filter($users, function($user) { return $user->subscribed('plan_name'); })`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I have no experience with `laravel/cashier`.

By taking a look at the [laravel/cashier](https://github.com/laravel/cashier) package, I have found the trait, [Billable](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/10.0/src/Billable.php) that the `User` model [should implement](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/billing#billable-model). In that trait there is a [`subscriptions`](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/10.0/src/Billable.php#L195) method that defines the relation. By looking at [the migration](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/10.0/database/migrations/2019_05_03_000002_create_subscriptions_table.php) of the subscriptions table we can see that a `Subscription` has a `name` property.

Knowing this information I assume you would want to do the following.

```php
$users = User::whereHas('subscriptions', function ($query) {
    $query->where('subscriptions.name', 'plan_name');
})->get(); // Or you can add your processed = 1 query as well.
```

This will return you all the users that have a subscription with `name` "plan_name".

**Edit**

In addition I can also see there is a `stripe_plan` property. You might want to try that one as well. However you might better of choosing the correct column by looking at the table in your database and check which column holds the "plan_name" value.